# Cgridview with data from 2 unrelated models

Tags: yii

I am slowly advancing yii
Not how to apply this:
I have a CGridView which shows me data from 3 related tables
I do it this way (modify the default generated by the crud:

model tabla1

```
public function search()
{
...
...
...

$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->with = array('tabla2','tabla3');
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->addInCondition('t.idtb1',1,3,5,6,7);
$criteria->compare('idtb2',$this->idtb2);
$criteria->compare('date',$this->date,true);
$criteria->compare('tabla2.codigo',$this->codigo,true);
$criteria->compare('tabla3.description',$this->descrip,true);

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                        'criteria'=>$criteria,  
));
}
```

The view

```
...
...
...
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'redeemed-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(        
        array(
            'name'=>'codigo',
            'value'=>'$data->tabla2->codigo',         
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'description',
            'value'=>'$data->tabla3->descrip',         
        ),
```

This shows me everything works perfect.
The problem is that I want to use two more tables that are not related, they are tabla4 and tabla5 and aggregate data from both tables to Cgridview.
  as can be done for linking data to table1 to be unrelated to tabla4 and tabla5?

Greetings and thanks

Comment: Are those values from tabla4 and tabla5 are static, or you want to have different values per row?

Comment: eg is related tabla5 tabla3, tabla4 tabla5 related to the problem is that there is no direct relationship tabla4 and tabla5 with tabla1

Comment: Whats an use case for a single table displaying unrelated data?

Comment: @Alexd2, in that case you can use `'value' => '$data->tabla3->tabla5->attr'`.

Comment: upload image of schema http://i45.tinypic.com/2cctts0.png

Comment: Add image cgridview, this is what I would like to add, tabla4 (nombre) http://i46.tinypic.com/24e83ub.jpg

Comment: Anyway you can use whatever relation you want. Try to use function as value if your relation is so complex: `'value' => function($data) { /* your code */}`

Comment: You can extend the example of how to apply, took two weeks recently with yii, thanks you